# Easiest way to link multiple cells to a combobox selection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combo box with 100 item numbers. I want my user to be able to select a item number, and have multiple cells from a table input into cells on a different worksheet. I could create a massive if/then statement but that would be exhausting. I was hoping someone knew of a more elegant solution.

For example, I could write a nested if/then statement like this:

If ItemNum.Value = "1001" Then

Sheets(10).Range("A2").Value = Sheets(11).Range("F2").Value

Sheets(10).Range("A3").Value = Sheets(11).Range("F3").Value

Sheets(10).Range("A4").Value = Sheets(11).Range("F4").Value

Sheets(10).Range("A5").Value = Sheets(11).Range("F5").Value

elseif ItemNum.Value = "1002" Then

Sheets(10).Range("B2").Value = Sheets(11).Range("G2").Value

Sheets(10).Range("B3").Value = Sheets(11).Range("G3").Value

Sheets(10).Range("B4").Value = Sheets(11).Range("G4").Value

Sheets(10).Range("B5").Value = Sheets(11).Range("G5").Value

Etc. 100 times

Comment: is it true that `1001` corresponds to columns `A` and `F`, `1002` - to `B` and `G`, `1003` - to `C` and `H` and so on?

Comment: Currently it's not so straightforward, but I could make it conform to that.

Comment: Can you describe more how the values get populated... According to your example, `1001` populates column A with the values from column F and `1002` populates column B with values from Column G... Can you be more specific? I think this can be done fairly easily, but before posting a solution, I'd like to ensure I completely understand your requirements....

Comment: @Giraffe, if it's possible I could write your code in three lines:) Also one Q: `ItemNum.Value` contains 1001,1002,...1100?

Comment: Here is what makes this complex. The item numbers are somewhat random (unfortunately I can't change them). So they run from 1001-1007, then 1017, then 5001-5003, then 9801 etc. It's completely convoluted but they have to match up with accounting.

Also, although most items only have 4 categories (Size, Type, Reflector, Wattage) there are a bunch of miscellaneous items that have their own categories. I suppose I can separate those out into their own If/Then statements.

Comment: That is still not a problem, but please post some explanation as to why you use completely different columns (A vs B)....

Comment: On my product list page, I have a bunch of different kinds of products from lights to sensors. The lights all have the standard categories (Size, Type, Reflector, Wattage) but the other items have their own categories. As I said before I can move around the columns on my products list page to easily match the columns on my Input Data page, so Size lines up with Size, Type with Type and so on. If that is whats required to make this easier for me then I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need VBA. Use Excel formulas: look into `MATCH`/`INDEX`, in paticular.

Comment: That's a great idea, but can I use those formulas in a user form?

Comment: The result can be reference from the user form.

Comment: Also, can you index multiple columns?

Comment: You can. It will see it as a 2D grid. However, I would isolate one column at a time, so that the formula will flex when I move columns (cut/paste) in the source sheet.

Comment: Right now I have the user selecting the item number and entering quantities into a user form. I'll have to use the application.worksheetfunction macro to pull this off but I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Okay so I tried writing a macro for it but it's giving me the "Unable to get the Match Property of the WorksheetFunction class error".




With Sheets("Review Lighting Data")

    .Range("i4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Product Pricing").Range("c7:c102"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ItemNum.Value, Sheets("Product Pricing").Range("b7:b102"), 0))

End With

Comment: Okay after trying a bunch of different ways to get match index working within the userform I decided to 'cheat' a little and just used the regular match index function in the cells. Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: lol. I actually prefer to use the least macro as possible. So using Excel functions within Excel itself would have been my first option.